# Import Clearcase View into Eclipse workspace, update maven dependencies, build workspace by command line Windows

Tags: windows, eclipse, command-line, batch-file, clearcase

WINDOWS 7

As the Title explains:

I have a workspace in eclipse, Also i have a Clearcase view (mvn clean install -- step done on the view). My this view has multiple projects.

Now i want to import this view into my workspace using command line (Please only command line). After importing , i want to do the regular stuff, like updating maven dependencies and building the workspace.

I would really appreciate if you could give me step by step command line way to do it.

Lets assume the dir..path of view is %View%

Lets assume that eclipse workspace %Workspace%

a) Importing all the projects from the view to the workspace.

b) Updating maven dependencies.

c) Building workspace.

d) Refresh

Thanks a lot for your time. I really appreciate it because, i have been stuck here from past 48 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I suppose you are referring to a ClearCase *snapshot* view (with files on `C:\...`). Any compilation on a *dynamic* view would be quite slow.

I am not sure you can easily import a project into an Eclipse workspace from command-line alone.
You could arguably write a plugin (like the one proposed in [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/tree/105360/#page_top)), but it is supposed to run from within an existing Eclipse session.

```
public void importProject(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
  System.out.println("Create the project : " + name);
  IProject newProject =
   ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(name);
  if (!newProject.exists()) {
    IProjectDescription description =
    ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().newProjectDescription(newProj ect.getName());
    description.setLocation(location);
    if (assertExist() && !location.toFile().exists()) {
      System.out.println("ERROR : " + name + " must exist");
    } else {
      newProject.create(description, monitor);
      newProject.open(monitor);
    }
  } else if (!newProject.isOpen()) {
    newProject.open(monitor);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I had this in my mind but i will keep this as the last choice. My script has a lot of stuff to do (this is just 5% of it). and i have to make it use as less time as possible.

Thanks anyways because this will help me write the plugin if i really have to have it.